# Dialog Box won't appear in Nougat ! Any one with solution?

Tags: android, android-7.0-nougat, android-7.1-nougat

My Dialog box looks like this.

```
d = new Dialog(context);
d.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
d.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.transparent);
d.setContentView(R.layout.layout_new);
 // Extra Initializations
d.show();
```

My Log

[image]
it wont appear on android nougat 7.0

> Screen just gets dark (normally like behind a dialog box)
>   Clicking on black empty area dismiss the dialog box(which is invisible)

Does any one have a solution to fix this ?

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: did the Dialog appear in other versions?

Comment: no it didn't disappear , On other versions it worked fine .

Comment: Can you post a simple project somewhere?

Comment: i found a hack to this bug ..
if i Create WebView(Context) and load some data into it . it fixes this issue and all dialogs can be opened.

[Hack Idea]
I have a dialogbox with Webview that load static offline page . opening that first of all does the trick and then rest could be opened. this gave me idea to create dummy Webview